# In what places/menus I can buy Special MK2 Ammo?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was wondering in what places or menus I can buy Special MK2 Ammo (Tracer, Hollow Point, Incendiary, Armour Piercing, Full Metal Jacket and Explosive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special ammo requires that you own a [Bunker](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bunkers) and have unlocked it via [Research](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Research).

Which research projects get unlocked is somewhat random; however, in my experience (and via friends), one of either explosive or incendiary rounds will unlock pretty quick, while the other will unlock nearly last. The remaining ammo types will unlock at some point.

With research, I find it best to set your initial spawn point in the bunker and restock supplies right away every time you load in. Then, I set my research staff to both, which didn't seem to slow the research progress down much.

Finally, once the ammo is unlocked, it can be purchased at any of your weapons workbenches. These can be found in:

- Arcade
- Terrorbyte
- Mobile Operations Center (with weapon workshop upgrade)
- Arena Workshop (with weapons expert upgrade)
- Avenger (with weapon workshop upgrade)

I also have my weapon loadout configured as follows (for maximum leathality):

- Combat MG -> FMJ rounds (pierces armored vehicles)
- SMG -> Hollow point rounds
- Carbine -> Armor piercing
- Assault Rifle -> Incendiary
- Bullpup Rifle -> Armor piercing
- Heavy sniper -> Incendiary
- Pump shotgun -> Explosive

I do not put special ammo in the Special Carbine nor the Marksman, even though you can. It's nice to have general purpose weapons with basically unlimited ammo, and Special Carbine is a beast with headshots.

Comment: Another way that I found is to accept a Contact Mission, buy the ammo from the menu and then leave (you appear in the same location in freemode).

Comment: Hmm, did not think of that... might be a new feature (I don't think it used to let you buy ammo for upgraded weapon magazine types from that screen).

Comment: Is not a new feature, when you are going to start an activity that uses weapons (Contact, Heist, GTA Race, etc) you can buy ammo while you wait for more players. The only drawback is that you need to select the MK2 weapon manually and buy the ammo for it, because you can't use Buy All to get MK2 ammo.

Comment: @theMayer Does the Terrorbyte require weapon workshop upgrade? Someone has suggested an edit to add this information. Please consider checking, and updating your answer if necessary. For now the edit is rejected because it attempts to change info in the post.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/363361/4797), there are new locations that have been added to the game where you can buy MK II ammo since that answer was last updated:

- **[The Freakshop](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Freakshop)** - You can access The Freakshop by finishing the [First Dose 1 - Welcome to the Troupe](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/First_Dose_1_-_Welcome_to_the_Troupe) mission. It comes with a [Weapon Workshop](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon_Workshop) for free. This is currently the only location where players can upgrade weapons to Mark II variants and purchase MK II ammo without needing to purchase a property.

The rest are in properties that you need to purchase:

- **[Kosatka](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Kosatka)** - - purchase the Kosatka and the Weapons Workshop upgrade.
- **[Agency](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Agencies)** - purchase the Agency and its [Armory](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Agencies#Armory) section

  > The optional Armory (if purchased) is staffed by the [Requisitions Officer](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Requisitions_Officer). This essentially provides the player with their own private [Ammu-Nation](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Ammu-Nation). The Armory allows players to purchase discounted weapons, upgrade selected weapons into [Mk II variants](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Mk_II_Weapons), buy [Body Armor](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Body_Armor) and [Parachutes](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Parachute) from the officer and a separate equipment section where they can also buy [Rebreathers](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rebreather), [Night Vision](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Vision) goggles and ear pieces. There is also a gun locker for custom weapon loadouts, and a counter beside it with free ammo pickups (24 rounds of Pistol and 24 rounds of Assault Rifle ammo) and a [health](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Health) pickup. Organization members, friends, and anyone else invited into the agency enjoys full access to the Armory and pickups, but not the discounted prices.

  <sup>- https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Agencies#Armory</sup>